# Implement generic return type for methods in Java

Tags: java

Hello  I have few model return types and a rest call that can have any one of those return type. I want to implement generics or something like that which enables to return the expected type model. For example:

Conside I have 2 models ItemDetails.java and ItemDetailsWithTimestamp.java
In one case i need to return the first model and in another case i want the second one:
I tried something like:

**`Test.java`**

```java
@Test
public void getitemTest() {
    ItemApi itemApi = new ItemApi();
    ItemDetails result = itemApi.getitem(ItemDetails.class);
} 
    
public void getitemWithTimestampTest() {
    ItemApi itemApi = new ItemApi();
    ItemDetailsWithTimestamp result = itemApi.getitem(ItemDetailsWithTimestamp.class);
}
```

And in the **`ItemApi`** class the method `getitem`:

```java
public static <T> ResponseEntity<T> getitem(Class<T> type) {
    #somecode for implementing rest calls
    return (ResponseEntity<T>) response;
}
```

Note: This is not the full code as seen but the extract which is perhaps enough to explain the problem. The above code returns an error on running the test:

java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to class myproject.model.ItemDetails (java.util.LinkedHashMap is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap'; myproject.model.ItemDetails is in unnamed module of loader 'app')

What could be the issues, is it not possible to accommodate different types using this approach or do i miss something. Thanks in advance,

Comment: You would need to show the code in "#somecode for implementing rest calls". Something in there is wrong.

Comment: Not just there, I'm actually wondering that this compiles. Shouldn't it be `public static <T extends ResponseEntity<T>> T getItem(Class<T> type)`? Also, this method is called in a non-static manner, which is no error but discouraged. Ultimately, I can't see how this code emits the given exception, since the only cast shown is one to `ResponseEntity`, but the exception was thrown on a cast to `ItemDetails`.

Answer (score 0):

One way to deal with this:

```
interface ItemDetails{}

class ItemDetailDtoWithTimeStamp implements ItemDetails{}

class ItemDetailsWithSomething implements ItemDetails{}
```

While returning, your return type should be `ItemDetails`(interface) and `ResponseEntity<ItemDetails>`

Comment: Is there a way to achieve  without modifying the autogenerated code.